# card game - what to put between the square brackets [ ]?

Tags: arrays, c

Im trying to do a card game (user vs pc) where the first to get 7.5 points win. For that I created a deck that have 4 suits with 10 cards each one. The cards go from 1 to 10, and the value of the cards 1-7 they value the number they have. Cards 8,9 and 10 value 0.5 points.

I created an array to store the cards and another to mark a card as deleted when chosen

```
int deck[40] = {1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,10,10,10,10};
int draw[40] = {0}; //array to "delete" a card. Mark a card as "deleted", e.g., by setting it to 1,
                    // then if the card chosen has been deleted, it choose again.
```

The thing is that I dont know what to put between the square brackets in draw[ ] = 1 for it to work

See my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
  srand( time(NULL) );
  int key, card, cardpc;
  int deck[40]={1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,10,10,10,10};
  int draw[40] = {0}; //array to "delete" a card. Mark a card as "deleted", e.g., by setting it to 1,
                   // then if the card chosen has been deleted, it choose again.
  float points, points_pc;

  printf("Press 1 to play or 0 to not!\t");
  scanf("%d", &key);

  printf("\n");

  if (key ==0){
  printf("BYE\n");

  }else if (key==1){
   while(key==1){
     card = deck[rand()% 40];
     if (draw[] == 1){
     card = deck[rand()% 40];
     }
     if(card==8 || card==9 || card==10){
        printf("You got 0.5 points");
        points = points + 0.5;
     }else{
        printf("You got %d points",card);
        points = points + card;
     }
     printf("\n");
     printf("Your score is: %0.1f \n", points);
   
     draw[]=1

     cardpc = deck[rand()% 40];
     if (draw[] == 1){
       card = deck[rand()% 40];
     }
     if(cardpc==8 || cardpc==9 || cardpc==10){
         printf("The PC got 0.5 points");
         points_pc = points_pc + 0.5;
     }else{
         printf("The PC got %d points", cardpc);
         points_pc = points_pc + cardpc;
     }
     printf("\n");
     printf("The PC score is: %0.1f \n", points_pc);
   
     draw[]=1;

     printf("Do you want another card? (Press 1 if you want it)\t");
     scanf("%d", &key);

     printf("\n");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need a separate variable:

```
int n = rand()% 40;
card = deck[n];
if (draw[n] == 1){
```

Comment: And once I have all cards chosen, that is, draw[40] = {1}, how can I make an statment to say: if all cards have already been chosen, the game ends. ??

Comment: @lusvi, just make a loop to check all the elements of `deck`

Comment: FYI, I would not choose your method of marking a card as `drawn` by setting it to `1`.   I would prefer to remove it from the deck.  That way, you don't have to repeatedly generate random numbers when you select one that is already drawn.  That will perform badly toward the end.

Comment: thanks! I have already managed to make it work